# How to replace words in text, if they belong to array with Javascript replace()

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, replace

I have a text like

```
const a: string = 'I like orange, blue, black, pink, rose, yellow, white, black';
```

And a string

```
const b: string =['black', 'yellow'];
```

I want to replace in string a all black and yellow to violet, so it must look like on the screen

**'I like orange, blue, violet, pink, rose, violet, white, violet'.**

I know about function replace(), but have no idea how to pass b as argument...Could you please help me?

And if it is possible I would like to replace not with violet, but with input field, so i could type my own colors right in the text...Thank you!

Comment: See the documentation for that function

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression with the given array, joined by pipe as OR sign in the regular expression.

```js
let a = 'I like orange, blue, black, pink, rose, yellow, white, black';
const b = ['black', 'yellow'];
   
a = a.replace(new RegExp(b.join('|'), 'g'), 'violet');

console.log(a);
```

With input

```js
function change() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
        a.replace(new RegExp(b.join('|'), 'g'), document.getElementById('input').value);
}

let a = 'I like orange, blue, black, pink, rose, yellow, white, black';
const b = ['black', 'yellow'];
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="" onchange="change();" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: @Arrow, she has not enough rep.

Comment: Do you know, it it possible to insert a input field, not the violet?  Like in example [link](http://imgur.com/3SliwK3)

Comment: Thank you again for you answer, but I meant a slightly different thing...So I would like to display text on screen, but instead of words from from array b, there must be inputs field, so I can type later different another colours and store it to array, so It will be array of my inputs. So like here, in this example [link](http://imgur.com/p9f0XCn) ...

Comment: i do not understand what you really want. maybe you ask a new question.

Comment: I guess there must be something like       a.replace(new RegExp(b.join('|'), 'g'), <input/>); , so I could replace words with inputs

Comment: it looks, you like to replace a position. the approach with replacing with a string, does not work, if the input shpuld replace the third color, or so.

Answer (score 1):

`replace()` doesn't accept arrays. But there is a work around. What you could do is loop over each word you would like to replace.

```
let a: string = 'I like orange, blue, black, pink, rose, yellow, white, black'

const b: string = ['black', 'yellow']

b.forEach(word => {
    a = a.replace(word, 'violet')
})
```

Also, `const` are immutable so if you want a variable you can modify make sure to use [let](http://wesbos.com/let-vs-const/).